# Sql select with Not exists

Tags: sql, select, where-clause, oracle12c, not-exists

I have a table like below :

TABLE_A:

```
Value  position  List    vehicle
---------------------------------
A       123        No      ABC
A       123        No      CDA
A       124        No      CDA
A       125        No      ABC
B       126        Yes     XYZ
```

I wanted to select the values from TABLE_A for each positions.

If the List is set to "NO" and if the position has this vehicle "ABC" and values in the position are same then I need to ignore this in my select. But if the position doesnt have this vehicle "ABC" and list is set to "NO" then I need to select that row.

I tried with "NOT EXISTS" but this returns nothing for the position 123 and 124. I except this to return the values of position 124 but it doesn't.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_A
WHERE VEHICLE IS NOT NULL AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT vehicle FROM TABLE_A WHERE position = 125)
  AND position = 123;

SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_A
WHERE VEHICLE IS NOT NULL AND  NOT EXISTS (SELECT vehicle FROM TABLE_A WHERE position = 125)
  AND position = 124;
```

For eg: if i select the value with poistion 124 i wanted it to return all the value of this position since it has no vehicle id "ABC" even though it has List "NO" but if i use the position 123 then it should not return any value since the position has the list "NO" and it has the vehicle "ABC"

Comment: Get rid of the semicolon `;` at the end of the `NOT EXISTS (......)`  lines -

Comment: Your exists are unrelated to your outer query. To which table does `position` in the exist refer to? The engine cannot read your mind, and may apply it to the outer query. Use aliasses

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM TABLE_A a
WHERE NOT (a.LIST = 'No' AND a.VEHICLE = 'ABC ') OR
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM TABLE_A a2
                  WHERE a2.position = a.position AND
                        NOT (a.LIST = 'No' AND a.VEHICLE = 'ABC')
                 );
```

That is, select all rows that are not 123/No.  Then select all rows for positions that only consist of such values.

You can filter for a particular position in the outer query just by adding `AND position = ?`.

If you want to do this for one position and only want one row, then a simpler formulation is:

```
select a.*
from table_a a
where a.position = XXX
order by (case when a.LIST = 'No' and a.VEHICLE = 'ABC' then 1 else 2 end) desc
fetch first one row only;
```

Comment: the first query is fine but it doesnt work in case of the position 123. It returns the row where the vehicle is not "ABC". the query shouldnt return any value if the position contains the vehicle "ABC" and any other vehicle along with it.

Comment: @newintodev . . . I confused the ABC and 123.  I fixed the answer.